# How to break out of a loop from a separate function

Tags: pi-3

In a python script, I want button-1 to call this function to flash lights:

```
def flash():
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
  GPIO.setwarnings(False)
  pinList = [4, 17, 27, 22]
  SleepTimeL = 1

  for i in pinList:
      GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
      GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)

  while True:
      b = random.choice(pinList)
      GPIO.output(b, GPIO.HIGH)
      time.sleep(SleepTimeL);

      GPIO.output(b, GPIO.LOW)
      time.sleep(SleepTimeL);
```

Within the same python script, I want button-2 to end the loop from previous function and turn off lights:

```
def alloff():
    pinlist = [4, 17, 27, 22]

    for i in pinlist:
      GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)
      GPIO.output(i,GPIO.HIGH)
```

How do I configure "alloff" function to stop the loop in the "flash" function before executing the commands in the "allof" function?

Comment: Although joan has already posted an answer this question is not really specific to the Pi. Although the question is somewhat related to the GPIO, the issue you raised here is more programming related. For programming specific questions please use [StackOverflow](https://www.StackOverflow.com).

Answer (score 3):

You define a global variable, perhaps called breakout_of_loop.  You test it in the while loop and stop if it is set.  You set it in the alloff function.